# Brotherhood of Steel Quests

Tags: fallout-4

How do I start some of these quests for Brotherhood of Steel?

These are some of the misc quests rumored, but I am unable to trigger them.

I have a fair bit of progression along the BoS line. I have taken multiple Quartermastery, Leading By Example etc quests and completed them.

- A Loose End
- Getting Technical
- Blood Bank
- Reactor Coolant

If it helps, I am yet to complete "The Molecular Level" quest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't completed the Brotherhood of Steel questline yet and like you haven't done more than multiple Quartermastery and Leading By Example quests (which are infinitely generating side quests and not story missions). However, the quest "A Loose End" references people and events that don't occur until after "The Molecular Level", and "Getting Technical" follows on from "A Loose End".

To start this question you will need to speak with Lancer-Captain Kells aboard the Prydwen.

I would suggest doing "The Molecular Level" using The Brotherhood of Steel's scribes to decypher the blueprints and the quests you've mentioned will unlock after that.

You must have also completed the Brotherhood of Steel side quest "Duty or Dishonor."

The "why" is explained here in this spoiler if you want more information (hover to show):

> The quest "A Loose End" allows you to convince the Captain to keep Virgil alive as an asset, assuming you've cured him. Since you get the retrovirus from inside the Institute's biosciences laboratory it wouldn't be possible to cure him before completing "The Molecular Level".

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate, and doesn't cover all the mentioned quests. I posted another answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've beaten the BoS quest line plenty of times, and I've done all these quests except for Reactor Coolant.

- **[A Loose End](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/A_Loose_End)**

This is for taking care of Virgil. It earns you a [legendary power armor helmet](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Visionary%27s_T-60c_helmet). According to the wiki

> The quest begins when the Sole Survivor speaks with Lancer Captain Kells during Liberty Reprimed, after the side quest Duty or Dishonor is completed.

Those prerequisite quests are after The Molecular Level. As for Virgil, he

> is an ex-Institute scientist that helps you infiltrate the Institute. He's become a Super Mutant due to his research, and Kells wants you to kill him.

- **[Blood Bank](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_Bank)**

This is a repeatable fetch quest that can be obtained by speaking with Scribe Neriah the first time you enter the Prydwen. It just earns you caps and the occasional [X-111 Compound](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/X-111_compound).

- **[Getting Technical](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Getting_Technical)**

This is a repeatable fetch quest that can be obtained by speaking with Scribe Quinlan the first time you enter the Prydwen. It just earns you caps.

- **[Reactor Coolant](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Reactor_Coolant_(quest))**

This is another repeatable fetch quest, but it's not available until you finish the main BoS quest line. It just earns you caps.